# How to determine that input (stdin) is broken?

Tags: c++, linux, posix

I'm developing a tool for coredump processing. Using `sysctl` I set it to obtain coredump on tool's input. Everything working great. But today I faced with situation when (I do not know why) coredump is broken. When I setting regular file as coredumps target - it does not appear. So - I supposed that it is broken for some reason. When I setup instead my tool `tee` - no result.

So. I want to determine such situation (if it is possible) and log it instead of producing broken files.

I'm using `::read(STDIN_FILENO,buff, buffSize)` to obtain data. And on end `read` just return's `0`. I want to indicate when `0` means the end of the file and when it means pipe is broken.

Comment: Did you check the result of the `read` call?

Comment: Yes, and I wrote about that in my initial message. Result is zero.

Comment: "on end it just return's `0`" sounded like you were complaining that `buff` had zeroes at the end. Please produce a [MCVE] next time. Right, so, what's the problem? If you get `0`, the pipe is broken.... what's missing?

Comment: I want to indicate when `0`  means the end of file and when it means pipe is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the bug in the program, *anything* could go wrong and there's no reliable way to detect *what* has gone wrong or even *if* anything has gone wrong.

As soon as a program exercises undefined behaviour or similar, *all* bets are off and the best you can do is *hope* that some reporting channel still works reliably.
Generally you can trust a core/mini dump written by the OS kernel to reliably capture the state of the program at crash time. But if your program has corrupted the stack or done other horrible things, the stack traces you'll get from those dumps can still be close to unusable.

Comment: I do not care about content of the coredump. I just want to inform user that coredump was broken due to smth. Without my tool such coredump just missing. Because file not finished. But my tool just finish the file when stop receiving input. So. Main questing - is it possible to determine that input was broken?

Comment: "is it possible to determine that input was broken?" - In many cases, maybe, probably. In the most general case. No.

Answer (score 0):

You've already found out: `read` will return 0, indicating that no bytes were read. For blocking streams like `STDIN`, that are supposed to wait until bytes *can* be read, that's an error condition.

You do not need "another API"; you simply need to read the documentation for the one you're using.